# Simplest possible table entry editing / addition / deletion web toolkit (for use with php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-plugins, tablelayout

I'm building a website in PHP and I have tables presented that I need to allow the user to:

1. add new entry (only one at a time, which should appear as a new modal overlay)
2. delete multiple selected entries from
3. edit an existing entry (only one at one time, in a view similar to 1.)
4. re-arrange entries up and down. One by one is fine. Multiple / Grouping rearrangements are not not needed

What jQuery / js / anything toolkit would be the SIMPLEST to work with? (of course, I should be able to work with it in php). I did try hacking away at: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/ but had a terrible time trying to get it to work on editing some existing data (had problem passing data to it).

Answer (score 3):

What about [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)? Here's a [demo](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)? of what it can do.

jqGrid is jQuery plugin which uses the jQuery UI for theming as well.

Answer (score -2):

There is a jQuery plugin called jQuery UI, did you try it?
http://www.jqueryui.com

Comment: Tried the jQuery plugin mentioned above. had a look at jqueryui, but dont see anything specific that would help me out here...

Comment: Does this tutorial help? http://www.hdeya.com/blog/2009/05/sorting-items-on-the-fly-ajax-using-jquery-ui-sortable-php-mysql/

Comment: No. I need it to do much more!! (and sorting isnt important at all for me)